# Безопасность при хотлинк

Tags: php, безопасность

**Задача:** Позволить пользователям включение в веб-страницу изображений с чужого сервера.

Что следует учитывать, чтобы сделать это безопасным?

Как проверить что ссылка ведущая на файл, является рабочим изображением не содержащим в себе вредоносный код, который, к примеру, будет воровать куки пользователя?

Comment: Если изображение не является изображением, то браузер просто не отобразит его. Код внутри изображения браузер выполнять не будет

Comment: А как такое. Создаем файл img.php, в котором вывод изображения и вредоносный код. В .htaccess через RewriteRule заставляем img.php отображаться как img.jpg. Теперь получается example.com/img.jpg...с виду изображение, но содержит вредоносный код. src в <img> принимает любые сслыки, даже если ссылка без расширения

Comment: Этот «вредоносный» код выполнится на сервере, а не в браузере. На браузер и на пользователя он никак не сможет повлиять

Comment: [PHP исполняется на сервере](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke)